# Preview Angular component with args and content in storybook MDX

Tags: angular, storybook, mdxjs, angular-storybook

We document our angular compnents via Storybook and normally use the MDX format for that

Given an angular component which requires content and accepts properties (via "Controls" Plugin) I have a problem implementing it into the story

For components that do not need content for content-projection I would simply do:

```
<Canvas>
  <Story
    name="Primary"
    args={{
      severity: "error"
    }}
  >
  {(args) => {
    return <inline-alert {...args}>The alert message<</inline-alert>
  }}
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

Which works regarding the args from the controls plugin. But the content "The alert message" is not applied.

Now I could do that:

```
<Canvas>
  <Story
    name="Primary"
    args={{
      severity: "error"
    }}
  >
  {(args) => ({
    template: '<inline-alert>The alert message</inline-alert>',
    props: { args }
  })}
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

This also applies the content. But how would I pass the `args` to the component? I could explicitely pass each arg, but that feels wrong....

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found a solution, feels a bit hacky but works.

I make use of @storybook/angular's `componentWrapperDecorator` which wraps the story INTO the component we want to preview.

Looks like so

```
<Canvas>
  <Story
    name="Primary"
    decorators={[
      componentWrapperDecorator(InlineAlertComponent, ({ args }) => ({
        ...args
      }))
    ]}
    args={{
      severity: "error"
    }}
  >
  {(args) => ({
    template: 'The inline alert content'
  })}
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```